# Layout editor in AS 3.4 RC does not allow to edit chain style in constrain layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I create new project and add to the layout three buttons, select them all and choose from context menu : chains -> Create horizontal chain. In editor I can see chains between buttons, but there is no icons to change style. According to docs:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain

icons should show below the buttons - but non are shown.

Is it a known bug in AS or maybe I am missing somethings?

btw. I use RC version because current official has other bugs - barriers are not shown in editor.

Comment: manually changing `layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle` works as expected